# is there something like a python parser for j2me?

Tags: java, python

I have a phone that does java and I want to program in bed, on my phone. 
Is there any (python) parser on java basis for J2me, possibly?
is there a website where I can write and test python code? Then I could code in Opera.

Comment: Are you looking for something like http://www.jython.org/ for Java ME?

Comment: yes. that is what i would be looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for the 1st question

see these links

http://isiam.blogspot.com/2007/01/jython-examples.html

http://www.awaretek.com/pymo.html

for the 2nd question

yes you can write python in a browser

http://codepad.org

http://py-ide-online.appspot.com/

there's also a bunch of extensions for google chrome like this one

https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/gdiimmpmdoofmahingpgabiikimjgcia?hc=search&hcp=main

I don't know if you find one for opera, I don't have opera so you have to check and see